# How to make slideToggle work only on first element clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple sidebar navigation menu with nested  elements setup like this:

```
<ul>
 <li id="nav-Heading1">Heading 1
   <ul id="nav-Expanded">
   <li>Heading 2
     <ul>
     <li><a href="link1">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="link2">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="link3">Link 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

All I am trying to do is have a slideToggle() setup so that when #nav-Heading1 is clicked, the ul with id of #nav-Expanded slides down or up.

If #nav-Expanded ul is visible, then you should be able to click on the links and go to the correct page in the website. Instead for some reason the slideToggle() is being applied to all elements so when you click on a link the entire #nav-Expanded ul disappears. I can't understand why its doing this. Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Expanded").hide(); //hides the Expanded nav initially 
    $('#nav-Heading1').click(function(e) {
           $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Expanded").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Updated:
Here is my JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vPb5V/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the clicks on the links are bubbling up and triggering the click event on the outer list.

Add:

```
$('#nav-Heading2 a').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();})
```

to your code to stop that.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tjBt3/)**

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Now I have another issue. After clicking on the link it goes to the correct page, but the navigation does not remain 'expanded'. Its hidden again because of the initial hide(). How would I go about keeping it open permanently until the user clicks on #nav-Heading1 again?

Comment: If you don't want the menu hidden when the page loads, remove `$("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Expanded").hide();`. However that will obviously leave it open for anyone who comes to the page. You may need to track your uses (the ones that click versus the new ones) with cookies or some other method, and then apply the `.hide()` based on if they're new or not.

Comment: I'm getting some strange effects with this code. Basically when I click on a link, it goes to the page, but the 'expanded' ul jerks awkwardly as if its trying to slide up but can't.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that should cause that. If you have more code than what you posted, that may be the issue. All the code does that I posted is cancel the click even from bubbling up the DOM.

Comment: You placed the `stopPropagation()` code inside your other click handler (wrong spot). Put it after like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vPb5V/4/

Answer (score 1):

Since your ul is children of `nav-Heading1`, a click on it will be a click on the `nav-Heading1`.

Try checking in which ul you click before toggling :

```
if (!$(e.target).closest('#nav-Heading2').length) $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Heading2").slideToggle("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. method**
The problem is that all elements inside `#nav-Heading1` will be binded to that event.
To prevent [event bubbling](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/) use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Heading2").hide(); //hides the heading2 nav initially 
    $('#nav-Heading1 > span').click(function(e){
       $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Heading2").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#nav-Heading2 a").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**2. method**

Wrap the clickable part of #nav-Heading1:

```
<ul id="nav-Heading1">
 <li><span>Heading 1</span>
   <ul id="nav-Heading2">
   <li>Heading 2
     <ul>
     <li><a href="link1">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="link2">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="link3">Link 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And now delegate the event to the span:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Heading2").hide(); //hides the heading2 nav initially 
    $('#nav-Heading1 > span').click(function(e){
       $("#nav-Heading1 ul#nav-Heading2").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```